# Результат функции при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, tkinter, button, return

Хочу создать функцию, при вызове которой создается новое окно с вопросом (принимается через параметр question_text) и двумя кнопками для ответа: Да или Нет.

```
def show_question(question_text):
    question_window = Toplevel()
    question_window.title("Подтвердите действие")
    question_window.geometry('300x100')
    question_window.maxsize(width = 300, height = 100)

    label_question = Label(question_window, text = question_text)
    label_question.pack()

    btn_yes = Button(question_window, text = "Да")
    btn_yes.pack()
    btn_yes.place(x = 90, y = 30)
    btn_yes.configure(width = 6)

    btn_no = Button(question_window, text = "Нет")
    btn_no.pack()
    btn_no.place(x = 160, y = 30)
    btn_no.configure(width = 6)
```

Вопрос как настроить функцию show_question так, чтобы в зависимости от нажатой кнопки — возвращались разные значения, "YES" и "NO, например?

Comment: Почитайте для чего нужен параметр command, который вы уже даже используете.

Comment: Я знаю, что через команд могу вызвать другую функцию, но даже если вызываться будет встроенная в show_question функция, как мне это поможет сделать return самой show_question?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть - как-то так?

```
yes_no = ''

def answer_yes():
    global yes_no
    yes_no = 'yes'

def answer_no():
    global yes_no
    yes_no = 'no'

def main():
    global yes_no

    show_question('Будем использовать результат?'):

    # Как-то пытаемся использовать результат
```

Здесь проблема в том, что переменная *yes_no* получит значение не после выхода из функции *show_question* а после того, как пользователь нажмёт одну из кнопок.  Как это организовать - зависит от Вашей программы.

Comment: Извините, но не вижу самого главного - возврата результата функции show_question.

Comment: @Vasiliy Функция *show_question* в принципе не может вернуть выбранное значение, так как в тот момент, когда она звершается, пользователь ещё **ничего не выбрал**.  Функции *tkinter* описывают структуру окна, а вовсе не последовательность действий. И эта функция описывает структуру своего окна. Она не знает, что там выберет пользователь через полчаса после того, как функция завершилась.

Comment: Я хотел избежать создание внешних функций и глобальных переменных, поэтому и полез сюда. Но вы думаете, что иначе никак никак?

Comment: @Vasiliy Лично я сделал бы так: 1) Окно выбора ответа создавалось бы внутри более глобального окна. 2) В этом глобальном окне была бы некая кнопочка "Сделать работу". 3) При нажатии на эту кнопочку (которое происходит заведома **после** ответа на вопрос, вызывалась бы некая функция, которая использует ответ.

Comment: Если не использовать глобальных переменных, то в Qt такие действия осуществляются с помощью сигналов, которые позволяют запустить разные действия в разных ситуациях.

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо